# Can't read dicom with SimpleITK

Tags: python, simpleitk

When i try to read a DICOM image with SimpleITK i get the following error:

RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ImageFileReader_Execute: D:\a\1\work\Code\IO\src\sitkImageReaderBase.cxx:102:
sitk::ERROR: Unable to open "C:/Users/egeoz/OneDrive/Masaüstü/Texts/Ders Notları/İmaging Ders notu/el.dcm" for reading.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdIci.png)

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read through [How to Ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

SimpleITK and ITK don't do a good job of handling non-ascii characters in the file names.  Also, I would suggest removing spaces  from the path too.